# Condional formating cell borders in excel 2010 with formula

Tags: excel

Is it possible to apply cell border color for values that fall within a specific range? with formula?

If so how? Instead of going to format instead of manually  selecting multiple cells and select "Format Cells" + click on the "Border" tab + apply "Color".

Comment: There is no formula to set a cell border, but you can use the "Conditional Formatting" feature in Excel to create rules which will setup colored borders around a cell.

Comment: If you must use a formula for whatever reason, you can define conditional formatting with VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Conditional Formatting**

1. Select the `cells` you want to format.
   [image]

---

2. Create a conditional formatting rule, and select the Formula option
   [image]

---

3. Enter a formula that returns TRUE or FALSE.
   [image]

---

4. Set formatting options and save the rule.
   [image]